# Ownership of Yahoo paper stock certificates

Tags: stocks

I have a paper stock certificate for Yahoo with them being sold recently what will happen? Will I just get a check in the mail? Will I need to do something?

I also read that Yahoo will keep their Alibaba stake does that mean my shares will be converted to Alibaba shares?

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/verizon-acquires-yahoo-2016-7

Comment: Yahoo hasn't been sold yet. As regards to your stock certificate rest assured you will be contacted if Verizon desires to buy your shares( not sure what SEC laws say about it though). Secondly it will be much easier for you if you get the certificate into electronic format by opening a brokerage account or get it converted if you have one.

Comment: @DumbCoder That's a good answer.

Comment: Side note: It isn't 100% sure Verizon will buy Yahoo. With the recent hacking of half a billion emails, Verizon might jump ship. So I wouldn't worry about your shares just yet.

Comment: @Dumbcoder why not add that as an answer so we can vote on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a paper stock certificate for Yahoo with them being sold recently what will happen? Will I just get a check in the mail? Will I need to do something?

The sale has not gone through yet. It is likely to be concluded by Q1 2017. Quite a few things will be more clear then.

Generally they way it looks like from the news is; There are 3 aspects ...

1. Portion that got sold to Verizon, you may get cash [not sure if these get converted into equivalent shares of Verizon for minority holders]
2. Cash that Yahoo has as reserves, Yahoo has mentioned this will be paid back to share holders.
3. The left over company will continue to operate as different brand [than yahoo]. So you will have same number of existing shares under a new name.

Even if you have paper shares, it is still the same. It may take longer for the Companies to factor this and may involve you returning the original share certificates for cash and new shares in left over company.

It is advisable if you get this converted into electronic form, then most of the process will be seamless.

Answer (score 1):

The current understanding of the deal is that Verizon will buy almost all assets of Yahoo. However, this is not a takeover. Yahoo legally continues to exist.

As a shareholder, you will still own part of the same legal entity. That legal entity just has a lot of cash, and may decide to pay a super-dividend or buy back stocks on the open market. Neither requires special action from you.